# Can not load XML file, because encoding fails

Tags: php, encoding, simplexml

This is the error occured:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: dump.xml:43: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xC7 0xD2 0xB7 0xCE in /usr/local/www/_test.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: <item id="740" name="'ÇŇˇÎŔŠ ČŁšÚ¸Ó¸Ž'" in /usr/local/www/_test.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /usr/local/www/_test.php on line 3
```

Whar is the problem?

I guess the problem is because by this string: `ÇŇˇÎŔŠ ČŁšÚ¸Ó¸Ž` but isnt there any way to force loading it?

Comment: Either define the charset, or use `iconv` to convert it to utf-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://yourwebsite.com/your.xml'));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

all data must be in UTF8. You need to convert your chars to UTF8

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php